# On event swipe in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

How to call an swipe event?. I want to trigger an event in swipe. The below code is works fine in normal query event. don't know how to achieve in meteor event.

```
  $('.your-class').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
    console.log(direction);
  });
```

in meteor:

```
Template.template.events({
 '???? .your-class':function(event, slick, direction){
    console.log(event);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the [hammer:hammer](https://atmospherejs.com/hammer/hammer) package.

And this `Events`

```
Template.NAME.events({
'swipeleft #hammerDiv': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // event
  },
'swiperight #hammerDiv': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // event
  }
});
```